# how to add a custom column to sales order grid in magento to show custom product attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Hello every one i want to add a column in sales order grid  to show custom attribute of products for exp : color 
Thanks you very much for help.

Comment: Override the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid and you can set the grid collection and column.

Add the column and set the value in collection

$this->addColumn('color', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('# Color'),
            'width'     => '80',
            'name'      => 'color',
            'index'     => 'color',

        ));

Comment: I am getting following error :- SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'color' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` ORDER BY color ASC LIMIT 20

Comment: yes you have to get the color column results and set to the collections.

Comment: Hello @user3040610 how can i set value in collection please help me i am new in magento thanks.

Comment: check this link http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/

Comment: Sorry but it's not help me @user3040610 i want to show custom attribute of product like :- color ,cost etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 :- Copy app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\grid.php
            to
app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\grid.php
Find   protected function _prepareColumns()
To Add column use this code:-

```
$this->addColumn('color ', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('color #'),
    'index' => 'color',
     'sortable'  => false,
            'filter'    => false,
    'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productatt',
));
```

Step 2:- Create a new file at :-

app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Renderer\Productatt.php
add this code :-

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productatt extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {                    

         $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));              
            $attribute ="";

        foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item){  
        $product    =   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());         
       if($product->getAttributeText('color')){
            $attribute .= $product->getAttributeText('color');
       }
    }
        unset($order);
        return $attribute;      
    }       
}
```

Comment: May i know how to solve this error, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSource() on boolean in C:\wamp\www\anc\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php on line 1385